# Nginx Webdav, client certificate

Tags: nginx, webdav, client-certificates

I am trying to create my private webdav server using nginx.
I set up the server to require a client certificate.
When visiting the site with the browser, the client certificate is requested.

However when I added a windows network location pointing to my server, it worked out of the box. It did not forward me to do anything, it just connected.

Obviously I do not want unverified access to my webdav.
What went wrong and how do I set this up correctly?

My config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
ssl on;
server_name XXX;

ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ca/ca.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;

access_log /var/log/nginx/XXX.access;
error_log /var/log/nginx/XXX.error;

location /data {
    #Webdav
    alias /media/webdav;
    autoindex on;

    dav_methods     PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
    dav_access      user:rw group:r all:r;

    client_body_temp_path   /tmp/nginx/client-bodies;
    client_max_body_size    0;
    create_full_put_path    on;
}

location / {
    return 404;
}
}
```